# Copying/reading value out of const multi dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm having a problem regarding const multi dimensional arrays.

This is my code:

```
const int a[3] = { 1,2,3 };
const int b[3] = { 4,5,6 };
const int c[3] = { 7,8,9 };
const int* arr[3][3] = { a, b, c };
cout << *arr[0][0] << endl;
cout << *arr[0][1] << endl;
cout << *arr[0][2] << endl;
cout << *arr[1][0] << endl; // error
```

The last line gives me this error:

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FF77B8839C6 in BitboardChess.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely
>   continued.

What am I doing wrong? Please help!

Comment: why are you mixing arrays of `int` with arrays of `int*` ?

Comment: `arr[0][0]` is `a`, `arr[0][1]` is `b` and `arr[0][2]` is `c`. You haven't set anything past `arr[0][2]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const int* arr[3][3] = { a, b, c };
```

Allocated an array of pointers to `ints` (`int *`) and initialized the first three locations with arrays decayed to pointers to `int`.

As soon as you hit

```
cout << *arr[1][0] << endl;
```

You'd run out of array elements you had personally initialized and attempted to dereference a zero-initialized pointer-- a NULL pointer.

How to solve:

```
const int* arr[3] = { a, b, c };
```

(But I'm not sure this will give the orientation you want) and

```
cout << arr[0][0] << endl;
```

Or discard `a`, `b` and `c` and initialize the 2D array all on one shot.

```
const int arr[3][3] = {{ 1, 4, 7 },
                       { 2, 5, 8 },
                       { 3, 6, 9 }};
```

(or maybe

```
const int arr[3][3] = {{ 1, 2, 3 },
                       { 4, 5, 6 },
                       { 7, 8, 9 }};
```

because I'm not still sure which orientation you're after) and

```
cout << arr[0][0] << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially only filling the first row of `arr`. The expression `a` is equivalent to `&a[0]`, the same applies to arrays `b` and `c`. You initialize `arr` like so:

```
const int* arr[3][3] = { a, b, c };
```

But this interprets `a`, `b` and `c` as individual `const int*`s, not as whole rows (array of `const int`). The rest of the elements are initialized as if they had static storage duration and point to null.